# "/dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors" at every boot, even after using fsck

Tags: boot, fsck

I encounter the following messages at every boot:

```
init: ureadahead main process (####) terminated with status 5
/dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
```

The check always passes with no errors.  I have used a LiveCD to run fsck on /dev/sda2 and initially it claimed the disk was clean and didn't need to be checked.  I then forced a check and everything still came out clean.  I have since tried rebooting the system normally several times and am still getting the above messages.  Is this a sign of a failing hard drive?

Comment: what is the FORMAT type of sda2. And since when it is happening.

Comment: EXT4 and it started earlier this week.

Comment: Did you resized any partition or shrinked any partition before this errors. Are you using RAID. Seems like init error , unable to read from particular drive , particularly due to changed UUID due to some reasons.Are you using Ubuntu 12.04 or earlier , pls mention.

Comment: I have resized sda2 before however it was a while ago and I didn't have any problems until this week.  No RAID.  Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: how many partitions are there , i mean is it only **/** and **SWAP** as default or please post if you partitioned for /home /var etc differently.

Comment: sda1 is boot, sda2 is /, sda3 is swap

Comment: just open your /etc/fstab `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`. Remove the entries that you added manually to mount drives at start up.

Comment: The only entries in my fstab are sda2 and sda3.  They both have the correct UUID.

Comment: I got that you tried , sorry for posting the same solution , and i can't find anything helpful since combination of these two error line is not found through all official sites. . If you are worried about Failing Disks run `sudo smartctl -HA /dev/sda` and alternately see its status in gui in [disks](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-disk-utility/)

Comment: This unanswered question about EOL Ubuntu 12.04 has likely gone away on it's own or was solved and OP neglected to post answer. VTC as `not reproducible`.